# Steps to configure jMeter with Android and ios devices in Windows to do performance testing

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do performance testing on Android and ios devices. But some how device is not getting connect to jmeter and steps are not getting recorded. Please suggest any best tool for performance testing on Mobile application.Also provide the steps to configure.

Regards,
AA.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy its verry easy to connect your phone with the proxy from de recorder.